# Mod Rewrite syntax: path to GET

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having a bit of trouble with the mod_rewrite syntax for Apache. Here's what I need:

The path

```
"www.example.com/public/path/to/file.txt"
```

needs to become:

```
www.example.com/public/?p=path%2Fto%2Ffile.txt
```

That is, everything after "public/" should be URL encoded and added as GET parameter "p". Any simple code snippets to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these rules in the htaccess file in the **public** folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?p=$1 [L,B]
```

The important thing here is the `B` flag which makes sure the `/`'s get encoded into `%2F`. Though, I'm not sure whether you really need it.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Is there a way I could make it do this while leaving the original URL in the address bar of the client browser? i.e. the /public/path/to/file.txt URL?

Comment: Ok, it seems there's a small error in your code. I think the last bit should be "./?p=$1 [L,B]" (note the leading period that's not in your snippet). Without this, it does some funky redirect loop.

Comment: @Jordan Yeah, sorry, forgot the htaccess was in the **public** folder. You can also do it so that the `/` is removed.